# How to document Form-based Authemtication implemented by spring security via spring-doc-openapi?

Tags: forms-authentication, openapi, springdoc

I'm implementing auth for my REST api and I have a problecm with docs. I wrote auth by spring-security form-based authentication. On success it gives me coockie to keep seesion authenticated. I have found no way to make spring-doc-openapi to find default spring-security controller for login/logout operations. The only way i found - make fakes of them like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class FakeSecurityController {

    /**
     * Implemented by Spring Security
     */
    @Operation(summary = "Login with the given credentials.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
                    description = "Login processing url",
                    content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = AuthDTO.class)),
                    headers = @Header(name = "SESSION", description = "Cookie", required = true, schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class)))
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "/login", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<AuthDTO> login(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                                         @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Add Spring Security to handle authentication");
    }

    /**
     * Implemented by Spring Security
     */
    @Operation(summary = "Logout the current user.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Logout processing url")
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "/logout")
    @SecurityRequirements
    public void logout() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Add Spring Security to handle authentication");
    }
}
```

What should i do to make spring-doc-openapi doceument these endpoints by itself?

Answer (score 2):

If your project that uses spring-security, you should add the following dependency, in combination with the springdoc-openapi-ui dependency: This dependency helps ignoring @AuthenticationPrincipal and provide the `spring-security` /login endpoint out of the box:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
      <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
</dependency>
```